# book on cubic fields by Kisilevsky

Tags: reference-request, field-theory

I have been trying to get a copy of

**Indices in cyclic cubic fields, in “Number Theory and Algebra”, Academic Press, 1977** by D. S. Dummit and H. Kisilevsky but it is nowhere to be found.

Does anyone know where I can purchase is or at least loan it or get it online?

Thanks

Comment: Apparently you want a paper from a Seminar or Proceedings book. Why don't you write directly to David Dummit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download it here https://archive.org/details/NumberTheoryAndAlgebra

Here are some more characters. Without them I can not post )

Comment: The [zero-width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) is a way to add spacers to your post without altering its appearance. For instance, my next comment consists of zero-width spaces.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​